# How to print a prenote in \listoffigures?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to have a little note (just a paragraph of text) appearing at the beginning of my `\listoffigures`, right after the heading, but before the actual list.

As I am using `biblatex` for handling my references, I am used to the `prenote` option to `\printbibliography`, which does exactly what I mean.

Unfortunately, there is no `prenote` option for `\listoffigures`. How can I achieve something like this with my `\listoffigures`?

I am mainly using KOMA script, so any solution that works nicely with its classes is preferred.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Do you mean some descriptive text after the heading before the list starts?

Comment: Yes, I do. How should I improve my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Class memoir

There is a hook `\cftlofbeforelist` in class `memoir`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtodef\cftlofbeforelisthook{%
  \noindent
  \lipsum[2]%
  \bigskip
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}\caption{My figure caption}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result memoir]

## KOMA-Script

KOMA-Script now uses package `tocbasic` for the lists. There `\AfterTOCHead` can be found:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AfterTOCHead[lof]{%
  \noindent
  \lipsum[2]%
  \bigskip
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}\caption{My figure caption}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result KOMA-Script]

Comment: I accepted this answer, because I am mainly using KOMA script classes, so `\AfterTOCHead` works best for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\addtocontents`, placing it as soon as possible, so its annotation will be at the beginning of the list. I've provided a way to add prenotes to every list, using the related extension as the first argument, but you need not specify them: just use the ones you want.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\addprenote}[2]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
    \protect\begin{quotation}
    \small\noindent\ignorespaces #2
    \protect\end{quotation}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\listoffigures
\addprenote{lof}{This is the introductory text for the list of figures;
  remember to protect fragile commands inside this text, like you would
  do in captions or section titles.}

\listoftables
\addprenote{lot}{This is the introductory text for the list of tables}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

Text

\begin{figure}[htp]
X\caption{Y}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
X\caption{Z}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested this method, and it works great. It's probably the best solution for people who do not want to use extra packages. However, as I am mainly using KOMA script classes, I accepted @HeikoOberdiek's answer.